# How to delete file in folder except name files in list.txt?

Tags: find, rm, delete

Assume in folder `/photo` have many files like

```
1.jpg
2.jpg
3.jpg
4.jpg
5.jpg
6.jpg
7.jpg
8.jpg
9.jpg
10.jpg
```

I have a file name `nodeletelist.txt` in this text file have name of not delete files list like

```
1.jpg
2.jpg
3.jpg
nodeletelist.txt
```

How to delete files:

```
4.jpg
...
10.jpg
```

except files `1.jpg`, `2.jpg`, `3.jpg` and `nodeletelist.txt` which in `nodeletelist.txt`?

Comment: Are you asking how to edit the nodeletelist.txt file, or how to delete actual files based on some modification of nodeletelist.txt?

Comment: How to delete all actual name of files in nodeletelist.txt?

Comment: I use this command for delete all files in list  deletelist.txt  , cat deletelist.txt | xargs rm -f | bash

But I want to delete all files except files in list  notdeletelist.txt
Thank you so much.

Comment: Is the "nodelete" file in the same place; should it get deleted, too?

Comment: yes, nodeletelist.txt in same place and not delete this nodeletelist.txt too.

Comment: Because UNIX allows newlines in filenames, can you declare -- in your question -- that none of the filenames in the file will have newlines in them? And that each filename is on its own line?

Comment: in nodeletelist.txt , name of files have newlines like
1.jpg --
2.jpg --

Comment: The point of the question is to confirm that you don't have a newline character in the middle of the filename. If one uses `\n` to represent a newline, can you confirm there are no files with a name like `12\nthis is a troublesome file.jpg`. Please edit the question to confirm this. Techniques for dealing with files are usually a lot simpler if it is known that there are no embedded newlines (which is the usual case).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For me the simplest and easy to remember and working also for very many files (thought would break on newline within filename but if You would have that You would have to think about Your list):

```
cd /photo
ls -1 | grep -v -x -f nodeletelist.txt | xargs -d "\n" -P 0 rm -f
```

If there is something else in the directory (subdirectories or different files, which I do not assume as You include Your txt in the list) I would use find I instead of ls (`find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -name "*.jpg"` for example).

Comment: It's working, Thank you so much.

Answer (score 4):

Do you have GNU find?

```
find photo -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -regextype awk \! -regex ".*/($(tr '\n' '|' < photo/nodeletelist.txt)nodeletelist.txt)" -delete
```

This works by using `tr(1)` and `find(1)`.

1. redirect the file into `tr`
2. replace newline with vertical bars, signifying "OR"
3. return that from the subshell
4. add a sentinel value at the end in case the file ends in a newline. 
   (In this case I used the name of your `nodeletelist.txt` as the sentinel,
   so you wouldn't need to include the file's name in the file
   if you used this solution.)
5. search the directory for entries exactly one deep below `photo`
6. use awk regular expressions
   to match the string returned from steps 1-4 above
7. delete files *not* matched by the regular expression
   (because `!` means "NOT")

The `-regextype` flag here could also be set to `posix-extended`, `egrep`, `posix-egrep`, `gnu-awk`, or `posix-awk` in this case as the extended syntax needed here works across them. The default findutils regexes, posix-basic, emacs, sed, etc., won't work with this command.

Comment: (1) Upvoted because you provided a good explanation, and you thought long and hard enough about the question to realize that the newline at the end of the list file could be a problem, and to realize that adding a “sentinel value” could protect against that problem …  (2) … although I believe that the newline at the end of the list file would not be a problem.  Can you provide an example where it would be?  (3) In Bash, you don’t need to escape `!` when it’s the last character in a word.  … (Cont’d)

Comment: (Cont’d) …  (4) It is possible for filenames to contain the vertical bar character (`|`).  Your answer would fail if there were any such files.  (5) Please don’t call `|` a “pipe” when you’re not using it to create a pipe.

Comment: Not all shells are bash.

Yes, I have seen many cases in which there's an empty line at the end of a file. I didn't have to think long and hard about that, because this is a standard pattern in regular use for that issue.

Comment: (3) OK; fair point.  Out of curiosity, what shells fail to handle a ``!`` by itself?  (2) You seem to have misunderstood my point.  I created a list of the files in a directory, putting it in a file called `nodeletelist.txt`, and then edited the file, deleting a couple of lines outright, and doing `D` on a couple (in ``vi``; i.e., deleted everything up to the EOL, leaving a blank line).  In particular, the file ended with a blank line; i.e., the last *two* characters were newlines.  … (Cont’d)

Comment: (Cont’d) …  Then I ran your command, replacing `photo` with **`.`** and `-delete` with `-print`, and, as expected, it listed the files whose names I had deleted from the `nodeletelist.txt` file.  Then I ran the command again, leaving out the ``nodeletelist.txt`` “sentinel”.  As expected, this time it listed the same names, but *including* ``nodeletelist.txt``.  In other words, no problem.  So my question to you is, why do you say “in case the file ends in a newline”?  Why is this perfectly routine and expected condition something you seem to want to guard against?

Comment: This solution with find may not be one of them, but there are a number of tools where you really don't want an empty entry at the end of the list. A sentinel is a good habit when constructing regex alternations on the fly. 

Consider what happens if you forget `-mindepth 1` here and don't use a sentinel.

Comment: OK, I’ve considered that, and I don’t see the issue.  So I come back to where I started: Can you describe a scenario where having the sentinel (vs. not having it) **makes a difference**?

Comment: Consider this, from the BSD-type find on macOS 12.5:

    % find -E test  -regex '.*/(one|)'
    find: -regex: .*/(one|): empty (sub)expression

Answer (score 3):

If `zsh` is an option, you could define a shell function to use as a "[glob qualifier](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Glob-Qualifiers)" for filtering the list of all files from the `*` glob e.g.

```
 % cmd() { ! grep -qF "$REPLY" ./nodeletelist.txt ; }
```

Then (from the `photo/` directory)

```
 % ls
 10.jpg   1.jpg   2.jpg   3.jpg   4.jpg   5.jpg   6.jpg   7.jpg   8.jpg   9.jpg   nodeletelist.txt
    
 % ls *(+cmd)                                         
10.jpg  4.jpg  5.jpg  6.jpg  7.jpg  8.jpg  9.jpg
```

Looks OK, let's delete

```
 % rm *(+cmd)

 % ls
1.jpg  2.jpg  3.jpg  nodeletelist.txt
```

There's probably a more efficient implementation that maps the file into an array first, and then tests whether `$REPLY` is an element of the array.

Answer (score 2):

Using `rsync` and move files to a dummy-directory `to-delete` then do a safe-cleanup:

1. run `rsync` command below in dry mode (remove `--dry-run` if result was fine)

   ```
   rsync --dry-run -v -d --remove-source-files      \
         --exclude='*/'                             \
         --exclude-from='/path/to/nodeletelist.txt' \
   /path/to/source /path/to/source/to-delete
   ```
2. remove the `/path/to/source/to-delete` directory created by `rsync` (note: *`rsync` can create last level directory in destination if it doesn't exist*) and the files moved there after double checking.

   ```
   rm -irv #/path/to/source/to-delete
   ```

   ---

explaining `rsync` options:

```
# --dry-run              'dry run'
# -v                     'verbose'
# -d                     'override recursive'
# --remove-source-files  'sender removes synchronized files (non-dir)'
# --exclude='*/'         'exclude all directories'
# --exclude-from='...'   'exclude list of files reading from specified path'
```

Answer (score 0):

For the stated case with no whitespace in the names

```
rm $(join -v 1 <(ls *.jpg) <(sed '$ d' nodeletelist.txt))
```

Assuming the last line of the file nodeletelist.txt actually reads `nodeletelist.txt`

If not, then just

```
rm $(join -v 1 <(ls *.jpg) nodelete.txt)
```

but it feels inelegant...